# Google app engine localhost server error python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, internal-server-error

I was just trying to run the hello world program in google app engine. But when I try to run the application on my browser I get a 500 server error. I tried re-installing both GAE app engine launcher and python 2.7.5. But no luck!

here is my **hello.py**

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: silent-blend-359
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
    script: hello.application
```

the log is to big so i  pasted it here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6195427/

**SOLVED**

I was using a proxy to connect to the internet. Just disabled the proxy and voila! Problem solved!

Comment: Are you also running cherry py at the moment? perhaps it's taking the port.

Answer (score 2):

Indendation is part of Python syntax. Indent correctly:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')
```

And, replace following line in `app.yaml` (There's no `application` in `hello.py`, but `app`):

```
hello.application
```

with:

```
hello.app
```

**hello.py**

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: silent-blend-359
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.app
```

Comment: that was a paste error. I checked the indentation. That is correct.

Comment: Did that. Still no luck.

Comment: @anik_das, Does it produce same error? If it produce another error, please post that error message.

Comment: @anik_das, I just tried the code myself. After fixing indent issues in `hello.py` and `app.yaml` and replacement (`hello.app`), it works as expected (show `Hello, World!`) if I access `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: yes! when I deploy my app to GAE it works perfectly. But I cannot access it from `localhost`. No idea how to solve!